# How to set horizontal overflow for QPlainTextEdit?

Tags: c++, qt, qplaintextedit

I'm trying to use a QPlainTextEdit but by default it go back at the next line when one is too long.

Is there anyway way to do a horizontal overflow (so to have a scrollbar instead and that the line continue 'endlessly') ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QPlainTextEdit has the method `setLineWrapMode(QPlainTextEdit::LineWrapMode mode)` you can use to set this property.

[setLineWrapMode(QPlainTextEdit::LineWrapMode mode)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#lineWrapMode-prop)

[image: Result widget]

- Through code:

```
#include <QPlainTextEdit>

QPlainTextEdit plainText;
plainText.setLineWrapMode(QPlainTextEdit::LineWrapMode::NoWrap);
```

- Through Qt Designer:

[image: Property picture]